# How do you copy formulas that reference other sheets from one Numbers spreadsheet to another?

Tags: numbers

What I’m actually trying to do is to copy the sheets from the included Retirement Savings spreadsheet into another spreadsheet.

However, while I can copy and paste the sheets just fine, they paste as values only, with no formulas. Copying and pasting the tables or cells does the same. Is there any way to copy formulas (specifically those that refer to other sheets) from one spreadsheet to another?

Comment: Okay, I’ve at least found a way to do so cell-by-cell: Double-click the cell, copy the formula, paste it into the new cell, then go to the beginning of the pasted formula and insert an “=“.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tried this lately as not needed to but I have taken the following steps to duplicate sheets with complicated formulae:

1. select rows or coluns or whole sheet as needed,
2. With Edit Replace, replace "=" with "xyxyxy" (or a text string never found,
3. Copy the rows, columns or sheet,
4. Paste in the new sheet at the desired location,
5. Now do Edit Replace to replace "xyxyxy' with "=",
6. test and save,

Always worked out for me as then any functions which are volatile, links to ranges etc are copied and pasted as text. Then they work once the "=" is restored.